# Google Play Game Services CAN'T GET STARTED.

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

My question is simple and vague. I can't get started in google play games. I need to create an application (in this case is a chess game that works in iOS and android). I've been doing the google tutorials but I can't create a game of my own.

I've done this quick [start](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/quickstart).

I can log in with my account to the game I've created and configured [here](https://play.google.com/apps/publish).

The status of my game is "Ready to Test."

This is a four man group project and I'm in the iOS development. I'm new to apple devices and objective C, so it complicates my life a little.

For the first app I'm trying to do anything at all, like a tic-tac-toe game or a "chat game."

I've searched for a tutorial that guides me step-by-step so I can get it.

Can anyone help me here please?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "can't get started"?

Now your status is get started, you need to:
* Add your account as the tester account in the game service console so that you can sign in with this Google account when testing your game.

- Implement the very basic code to access game service (sign in, leaderboard and/or achievements, etc.), which I assume you have already done if you have followed the quick start.
- Test your game. You can provide a button in the game UI and when you click that button, perform the sign-in process. If you have already implement the leaderboard/achievements, you can also check them.

Comment: yes, the sign is is basic and simple, the problem was to create a game and the turns... There is NO tutorials to create an app with this services...

Comment: I think the quick start is somehow a tutorial, and you can also check the samples. About how to use the services, the quick start has give some examples, and you just need to change some parameters to your own ones.